# How do you get the top menu settings back

Tags: interface

For some reason, Blender isn't letting me getting to the "File Edit Change", like the top menu that usually all programs have. This is the weirdest problem I have ever had, and here's the screenshot:

[image: Stupid blender.]

As you can see, there's no menu at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Just drag from the *3D View* corner up to create a new window. Place where desired and the change the editor type to *Info*

[image: Info Window]